# Hawtio shows blank page

Tags: hawtio

After building Hawtio 1.4.27 from source, and running "mvn clean jetty:run" as per the instructions at http://hawt.io/building/ I am connecting to a remote Tomcat server, which includes jolokia. A new tab opens but with a blank page. If you "view source" it looks like it's all there but nothing appears.

EDIT: In the browser Console I just noticed two errors on the blank page:

```
[Window] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value (<a href="localhost:8282/hawtio/lib/…) loggingInit.js:57 consoleLogger loggingInit.js:57 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:8282/hawtio/welcome?con=local%20tomcat
```

Also, I installed the latest (1.4.4) Chrome plugin with the latest Chrome (38.0.2125.104) and it doesn't seem to work at all. When you press Connect nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into [this issue](https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/1699) myself and fixed it, any chance you could try the current master branch and see if that helps?  If not please raise an issue on our issue tracker, thanks!

Comment: Thanks Stan, I will try it out as soon as I can and get back to you.

Comment: I tested this with tag 1.4.29 and also with master (1.5-SNAPSHOT). Both these are working, it seems the problem is fixed. Thanks again!